# How do I get dots in numbering in enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate

Consider this simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
Blah.
\begin{enumerate}[i.]
\item 
\label{petite}
Petite blah.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

In Step \ref{petite} we see nothing.
\end{document}
```

The last line reads `In Step 1i ...`, but I would like it to read `In Step 1.i ...`. How can I make LaTeX add a dot between the numbering?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Switch to modern and more powerful `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
Blah.
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*.,ref=\theenumi.\roman*]
\item
\label{petite}
Petite blah.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

In Step \ref{petite} we see nothing.
\end{document}
```

[image]